# ProviderError: HttpProviderError at HttpProvider.request (.../node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/providers/http.ts:78:19)

Tags: node.js, solidity, truffle, dex, hardhat

i was tring to deploy a dex in my testing envirolment
this is the link to github repo
https://github.com/hamed-elahifar/geoswa3

this is the steps in deploy.js script
in the main function
at first we deploy erc20 tokens
after that router and factory for swap deployed
next step will approve router to use erc20 tokens
after that script create pair in swap and add liquidity to them
next step is adding these pairs to farm, but we got following error

ProviderError: HttpProviderError at HttpProvider.request (.../node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/providers/http.ts:78:19)

i expect addPool function in farm execute like other fucntions

Comment: One or possible more arguments set up in your `.env` file is wrong [here](https://github.com/hamed-elahifar/geoswa3/blob/master/env.sample).

Comment: If you want to look for internal implementation: [here](https://github.com/NomicFoundation/hardhat/blob/0d216049236a53fc28ca9d7b8c5b36df0c42891f/packages/hardhat-core/src/internal/core/providers/http.ts#LL78C5-L78C23)

Answer (score 0):

It is not direct solution to your problem, but you can add some lines to `node_modules/hardhat/internal/core/providers/http.js` to debug. After `isErrorResponse` checks, add: `console.log(response)` or `console.log(jsonRpcResponse)`.